# Unique name for flip (.)

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know of a good name for `flip (.)` that doesn't collide with `lens` or `base` (at least the commonly used subset of it)?

Please provide your answers as answers, not as comments (even if they are very short).

Comment: @Zeta No, `(&)` is `flip ($)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Good point, indeed. That's it for today, I presume.

Comment: @Zeta `(<&>)` does fit though.

Answer (score 6):

`>>>` from `Control.Arrow`

`|>` is also a good candidate, from F#

Comment: ideally there would be a one character name

Comment: Looking at some of [the F# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx), it appears `>>` is `flip (.)` while `|>` is `flip ($)` (aka `(&)` from package lens).

Comment: @LucDanton, what does F# have to do with anything?

Comment: @dfeuer I said `|>` was from F# (@LucDanton IMO using it here for a slightly different meaning is fine)

Comment: I was introduced to F# before Haskell, so I used to define to `(|>)` as-well. However users should keep in mind the operator is used with [sequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:-124--62-), so imo a good alternative could be `($>)` to both lessen conflicts and imply an application (I personally use `($>>)` to also imply the pipeline is going forward and not immediately-forward).

Comment: F#'s `|>` is **not** Haskell's `>>>`.

Answer (score 6):

`(<&>)` from `lens` also fits, although its type is more general.

Answer (score 4):

I used to use `.>` for `flip (.)` (and `|>` for `flip ($)`) many years ago, but eventually I got over it and learned to use the standard operators. I think it's a mistake to look for a single character for it, and today would use `>>>` from Control.Arrow.